# Program runs but doesn't not display accurate data

Tags: c, arrays

I am in the process of finishing up a program for my Intro. to C class and it is running without errors or warnings.  The problem is that when I input the required data it does not return sums or averages, it only returns zeros.  I have spent the past day reviewing my code and checking each line, but I cannot find what I did wrong.  I appreciate any help you can give me.

The assignment:

Write a function, named sums(), that has two input parameters; an array, called Input of doubles; and an integer which is the number of values stored in the array. Compute the sum of the positive values in the array and the sum of the negative values. Also count the number of values in each category. Return these four answers through output parameters. Write a main program that reads no more than 10 real numbers and stores them in an array. Stop reading numbers when a 0 is entered. Call the sums() function and print the answers it returns. Also compute and print the average values of the positive and negative sets. Align decimal points on numbers

SAMPLE INPUT: 
-123.45
-234.56
576.1
-9.345
675.2
100
-10
1654.45
765.89
0 (NOT in computation)

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

YourName Program#8 CSCI1110

Input Read:
9999.9999
9999.9999
...

Statistics:
Desc     Number     Total:      Average:
Positive  99     99999.9999    9999.9999
Negative  99     99999.9999    9999.9999
Overall   99     99999.9999    9999.9999

----PARTIAL SAMPLE OUTPUT:
Negative   4       -377.3550    -94.3388

Your function call will look something like sums(input[], n, &sumPos, &sumNeg, &countPos, &countNeg)

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sums(double arrayN[], int size, double *sumPositive, double *sumNegative,
          int *numberPositive, int *numberNegative)

{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++);

    {

        double currentNumber = arrayN[i];

        if (currentNumber < 0.0)

        {

            *sumNegative = *sumNegative + currentNumber;

            *numberNegative = *numberNegative + 1;

        }

        else

        {

            *sumPositive = *sumPositive + currentNumber;

            *numberPositive = *numberPositive + 1;

        }
    }

}

int main(void)

{

    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    double number[ARRAY_SIZE];
    double num;
    int all = 0;
    double positiveSum = 0;
    double negativeSum = 0;
    int countPositive = 0;
    int countNegative = 0;
    double sumAll = 0;
    double avgAll = 0;
    double avgPositive = 0;
    double avgNegative = 0;

printf("Enter Real Numbers:\n");

scanf("%lf", &num);

sums(number, all, &positiveSum, &negativeSum, &countPositive,
     &countNegative);

while(all < ARRAY_SIZE && num != 0)

{

    number[all] = num;

    all++;

    scanf("%lf", &num);
}



sumAll = positiveSum + negativeSum;

if(all != 0)

    avgAll = sumAll / all;

if(countPositive != 0)

    avgPositive = positiveSum / countPositive;

if(countNegative != 0)

    avgNegative = negativeSum / countNegative;

printf("Kevin C. Ellis   Program #8  CSCI 1110  Section 3\n");
printf("\nStatistics:\n");
printf("Desc\t\tNumber\t Total:\t\tAverage:\n");
printf("Positive\t%d\t%.4lf\t%.4lf\n",countPositive, positiveSum, avgPositive);
printf("Negative\t%d\t%.4lf\t%.4lf\n",countNegative, negativeSum, avgNegative);
printf("Overall\t\t%d\t%.4lf\t%.4lf\n", all, sumAll, avgAll);

return 0;


}
```

Comment: You're using the `number` array before actually reading values into it.

Comment: What are all these blank lines in your code for ?

Comment: You might like to read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn on how to help yourself in such cases.

Comment: Also do yourself a favour and properly format/indent your code.

Comment: step through the code with a debugger - what platform?

Comment: Thank you all for the help so far.  I will read everything you commented on and work your suggestions.  I will report back when I am done.  I just had a project for another class dumped on my lap (gotta love "teamwork"), but I will get back to this in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

In function "sums" remove ';' just after for loop otherwise loop will not work correctly

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++);
```

after removing ';'

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

Comment: `clang` will flag this with a simple `-Wall` but `gcc` needs an explicit `-Wempty-body`